# best way to present multiple listview

Tags: flutter, listview, structure

I would like to know your idea about the best method to present several personalized horizontal lists, in the spotfy style.
With different preferences and musical styles.
The best way would be to create several listviews? or structure a database and make it somehow present only a few things on the user's homepage?
any suggestion?

Comment: I will go for `CustomScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there would be any problem displaying different list view on home showing few items ( 3 or 4 ) of that list and a button above each listView as View All on tapping using that list all items on that category personal screen

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple ListView as you can possible Try `SingleChildScrollView` for multiple `ListView` or `Layouts`

Refer Official Docs : [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).